# How do I get only the value of index[0] to display of an array in a JSON object?

Tags: arrays, json, angular, angular2-forms

I have a JSON object 'user' in a user.ts file listed below:

```
ngOnInit() {

    // initialize user model here
    this.user = {
        cardholder: '',
        place: '',
        site:'',
        building: '',
        group: '',
        justification: ''
    }
}
```

In my page.component.html, the user is filling out a form, one component being a drop down menu. The drop down menu gets assigned to the JSON object, and I can see it being assigned using the {{ user | json }} notion.

```
<div>
    <label>Select A Site</label>
    <select name="site" [(ngModel)]="user.site">
        <option *ngFor="let site of sites" [ngValue]="site">  
            {{site.display}}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I am showing a summary panel on the side that shows the user what they have selected in their form, and when I do `{{user.site}}`, I see object, object displayed.

```
<p><span class="step"> Step 3: </span> Site: {{user.site}}</p>
```

I know that site is an array, with index[0] = value, index[1] = display.

```
public sites = [
    { value: 'sunshine', display: 'Sunshine' },
];
```

How do I get only the value of index[0] to display of an array in a JSON object,  and not the whole JSON object associated with "user.site"?

Comment: Could you post a link to a mock on codepen or something? There's a few confusing points here. First, is this.user really json? It looks like a normal object. I'm not sure what you mean by "I know that site is an array, with index[0] = value, index[1] = display". Sites is the array that your ngFor will iterate over to create each option element, but the site is not an array, and it will not have indexes.

Aside from that, this may be as simple as changing your ngValue to point to "site.value."

Comment: that worked perfectly. [ngValue]="site.value", thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning object rather than string.

**Solution 1**

```
<select name="site" [(ngModel)]="user.site">
    <option *ngFor="let site of sites" [ngValue]="site.value"> <===== site.value rather than site 
        {{site.display}}
    </option>
</select>
```

**Solution 2**

```
<p><span class="step"> Step 3: </span> Site: {{user.site.value}}</p>
```